# how detect id in click event after appending HTML

Tags: jquery, append

I have this code that appends html into a div tag with `getPhotoUpdate` ids...:

```
var newelement = '<div id="' + data.id + '_" class="card col-md-3">
<img src="' + data.addr + '"' + ' >' +
        '<i data-deleteId="' + data.id + '" class="icon-close btn-delete"></i></div>';

$('#getPhotoUpdate').append(newelement);
```

and html code

```
<div id="getPhotoUpdate">
@foreach ($photos as $item)
    <div id="{{'k'.$item->id}}" class="card col-md-3">
        <img src="{{asset('public/'.$item->img_url)}}"
             width="100%" alt="Card image cap"
             height="200">
        <i data-deleteId="{{$item->id}}"
           class="icon-close btn-delete">
        </i>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

After appending, I want to click on the btn-delete button and delete the image؛ but I do not know how to send the photo id to the click event!!!

```
$('#getPhotoUpdate').on('click', '.icon-close[data-deleteId]', function () {
        let id__ = $(this).children('.icon-close').attr('data-deleteId');
        console.log(id__);          //  id__ is undefined
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already listening on a click event for `.icon-close`. Therefore, your issue is that this:

```
$(this).children('.icon-close').attr('data-deleteId');
```

should be:

```
$(this).attr('data-deleteId');
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#getPhotoUpdate').on('click', '.icon-close[data-deleteId]', function() {
  let id__ = $(this).attr('data-deleteId');
  $(`#${id__}`).remove();
});


const newelement = `
  <div id="1_" class="card col-md-3">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="">
    <i data-deleteId="1_" class="icon-close btn-delete">delete</i>
  </div>
`;


$('#getPhotoUpdate').append(newelement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getPhotoUpdate"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w2pdgtn9/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it was true... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your event's target is the same element you're looking for that data value on.

Replace:

```
$(this).children('.icon-close').attr('data-deleteId');
```

with simply:

```
$(this).attr('data-deleteId');
```

or a bit more jQuery-ish:

```
$(this).data('deleteId');
```